# Any suggestions to improve my PDO connection class?

Tags: php, pdo

I am pretty new to pdo, so I basically just put together a simple connection class using information out of the introductory book I was reading. But is this connection efficient? If anyone has any informative suggestions, I would really appreciate it.

```
class PDOConnectionFactory{

    public $con = null;
    // swich database?
    public $dbType  = "mysql";
    
    // connection parameters

    public $host    = "localhost";
    public $user    = "user";
    public $senha   = "password";
    public $db  = "database";
    

    public $persistent = false;
    
    // new PDOConnectionFactory( true ) <--- persistent connection
    // new PDOConnectionFactory()       <--- no persistent connection
    public function PDOConnectionFactory( $persistent=false ){
        // it verifies the persistence of the connection
        if( $persistent != false){ $this->persistent = true; }
    }
    
    public function getConnection(){
            try{
                $this->con = new PDO($this->dbType.":host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->db, $this->user, $this->senha, 
                array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => $this->persistent ) );
                // carried through successfully, it returns connected
                return $this->con;
            // in case that an error occurs, it returns the error;
            }catch ( PDOException $ex ){  echo "We are currently experiencing technical difficulties.  ".$ex->getMessage(); }

    }
    
    // close connection
    public function Close(){
        if( $this->con != null )
            $this->con = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would rename `public $persistent` to `public $isPersistent` (matter of taste there) and also adjust the constructor `if` line to instead read just simply `$this->isPersistent = $persistent;`. The other `public` variables ($con, $dbType, $host, $user, $senha, $db) should probably be `private`. When implementing a "Factory" usually it is so that other classes, methods, etc using it don't have to know or care about the connections, usernames, passwords, etc.

Comment: do you know if this process is efficient? is there a better way? I haven't yet had time to learn coding patterns and OOP in more depth so I am just looking for a place to start so I can sustain my site until I update it.

Comment: This is the start to a "better way". If you practice Separation of Concerns, you won't have as hard of a time when you maintain your code later. However, if you sprinkle mysql connection objects and select statement strings all over your pages, you are going to have issues. Instead if you separate out your database layer using a class even something as simple as create a class called `DataAccessLayer` with a function called `GetThing()` and then `$dal = new DataAccessLayer()` and call `$dal->GetThing()`, you will have an easier time maintaining your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When implementing a "Factory" usually it is so that other classes, methods, etc using it don't have to know or care about the connections, usernames, passwords, etc.

I would do it something more like:

```
static class PDOConnectionFactory {
    // database
    private $dbType = "mysql";

    // connection parameters
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "user";
    private $senha = "password";
    private $db = "database";

    // new CreateNewConnection( true ) <--- persistent connection
    // new CreateNewConnection()       <--- no persistent connection
    public function CreateNewConnection($persistent = false) {
        try {
            $con = new PDO($dbType . ":host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $senha, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => $persistent));
            // carried through successfully, it returns connected
            return $con;
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) {
            // in case that an error occurs, it returns the error;
            echo "We are currently experiencing technical difficulties. We have a bunch of monkies working really hard to fix the problem. Check back soon: " . $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you use the connection returned by CreateNewConnection() in whatever way you need.

I didn't check if the above code compiles, there could be a few typos/issues, but you get the idea. Now you need to take it a step further and implement something like the repository pattern :)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you implement a singleton to restrict the instantiation of PDO to one single object. It might look like this:

```
class Database {

    protected static $_instance;
    protected $_connection;
    protected $_dns = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydbname';
    protected $_username = 'myusername';
    protected $_password = 'mypassword';

    /**
    * Singleton pattern implementation makes "new" unavailable
    */
    protected function __construct()
    {
        $this->_connection = 
            new PDO($this->_dns, $this->_username, $this->_password);
    }

    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->_connection;
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (null === self::$_instance) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    /**
    * Singleton pattern implementation makes "clone" unavailable
    */
    protected function __clone()
    {}
}


$dbc = Database::getInstance()->getConnection();
```

Comment: what is the benefit of switching?

Comment: This pattern is intended to avoid multiple instances. When working with a database connection, you normally want to open that connection only once, not every time you request the PDO object. That's why the constructor and the __clone methods are not public. Its instantiation is always handled by getInstance().