# Prblems with setting PDO connection global

Tags: php, pdo, global-variables

after reading a lot of post but not getting this thing running, maybe somone can help me  with this.

I am trying to include a PHP (Module.php) file which craps information from db  into my index.php. This index.php also includes the file with the database connection. The problem is the included file which handles the db selects seems not to know about the PDO Object, the Script dies which this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
```

I tried to make the PDO Object global. But unfortunately this is not working.

Thanks a lot for any help (and safe me not going crazy ...)

Tony

index.php

```
//DB Connection
require_once ("include/db_connect_inc.php");

$request = $_GET['Controll'];

switch ($request) {
case 0:
    echo "XY";
    break;
case 1:
    global $objDb;

//This file should be able to use the DB Object
    include("modules/Eat/Module.php");
    break;
```

}

Module.php

```
global $objDb;

    $dbSelect = $objDb->prepare(
    "SELECT DISTINCT ON (nummer) nummer
    FROM tableX
    "  
);

$dbSelect->execute();

while($row = $dbSelect->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
$all = $row['nummer'];
}
echo "1 - " . $all;
```

db_connect_inc.php

```
$strDbLocation = 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=test';
$strDbUser = 'root';
$strDbPassword = 'root';

try{
    $objDb = new PDO($strDbLocation, $strDbUser, $strDbPassword);
    $objDb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $objDb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    global $objDb;
}
catch (PDOException $e){
    //echo 'Fehler beim Öffnen der Datenbank: ' . $e->getMessage();
       print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Your use of global is completely incorrect. There are no functions in the code you have provided, `$objDb` is in the same scope for all of the files.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't seem to use any functions, your variable is already set in the global scope, so you should get rid of all the `global $objDb;` lines.

That should solve the problem as long as there is no error in the first 3 lines where you connect to the database.

Apart from that I would use OOP / classes and use dependency injection to make sure my `Module` class is always provided with the stuff it needs (a db connection in this case).

Comment: mhhh .... The global lines where only the last try after hours. I tried it without this before. And it didn´t work. I have checked the connection this seems to be correct.

Comment: @t Book What error do you get without any of the `global` lines? You can start with adding a `var_dump($objDb);` after each of the db connection lines (`new PDO` until after the last `setAttribute`).

Comment: Hi jeroen, the error stays the same if I kick everyhing global out Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Comment: thats the var_dump object(PDO)#1 (0) { } object(PDO)#1 (0) { } object(PDO)#1 (0) { }

Comment: okay, sun is shining I found this singelton class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010097/any-suggestions-to-improve-my-pdo-connection-class which I don´t understand but it´s working meand good for learning! thanks to everybody