# PDO Connections - max connections

Tags: php, class, pdo, database-connection

I have the following class:

```php
<?php
class Database {

    protected static $_instance;
    protected $_connection;
    protected $_dbhost=DB_HOST;
    protected $_dbname=DB_DBNAME;
    protected $_username = DB_USER;
    protected $_password = DB_PASS;
    protected $_dbType = "mysql";

    /**
    * Singleton pattern implementation makes "new" unavailable
    */
    protected function __construct()
    {
        $this->_connection = 
            new PDO($this->_dbType . ":host=" . $this->_dbhost . ";dbname=" . $this->_dbname, $this->_username, $this->_password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8", PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
    }

    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->_connection;
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (null === self::$_instance) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    /**
    * Singleton pattern implementation makes "clone" unavailable
    */
    protected function __clone()
    {}
}

?>
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010486

Now  I have a second class, which has all the functions that access the DB.

**My question:**
I had a problem with max connections in my script, therefore I use the new Database class. In my helper class I do it like this:

```php
<?php   
class helper {

    function getAllInvitesFromPlayer($uid) {
        $sql = "SELECT request_id FROM ".DBPREFIX."invites WHERE inviter_id = :uid AND joined = 1";

        try {
            $db = Database::getInstance()->getConnection();
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam("uid", $uid);
            $stmt->execute();
            $content = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
            $db = null;
            return $content;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

After the "try" is it correct to use the `$db = Database::getInstance()->getConnection();` or shall I "outsource" it to a class variable and access it like `$this->_db;` in each function and try ?
What is better to avoid getting too much connections to my db?

And its surely better just to initialize the helper class once in a file, right? and not always calling `$helper = new helper()` because this would always create a new DB connection, right?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter.
As long as you are using `getInstance()`, it would be always the same single connection, no matter which way or where you call it.

For sake of incapsulation, it's better to assign db connection to a class variable.

Also note that your use of try..catch is wrong. It shouldn't be there.

So, something like this

```
<?php   
class helper {

    protected function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = Database::getInstance()->getConnection();
    }

    function getAllInvitesFromPlayer($uid) {
        $sql = "SELECT request_id FROM ".DBPREFIX."invites WHERE inviter_id = ? AND joined = 1";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($uid));
        return $stmt->fetchColumn(); // will return one invite actually
        //or
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0); // will return ALL invites indeed
    }
}
```