# pdo connection position in php class

Tags: php, pdo, database-connection

I'm using PDO now and I have a number of classes. 
Every time I use a class, I don't always use its database-related functions. Sometimes I keep using a class until at the end I might do some work with the database, like save this object to DB.

So I'm currently doing something like this:

```
class Something
{
   protected $pdo;

     function connect()
     {
        $this->pdo = new PDO( "mysql:host=".zConfig::read('hostname').";dbname=".zConfig::read('database'), zConfig::read('username'), zConfig::read('password'));
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     }

     /* lots of functions doing lots of non-DB things */

     function saveToDB()
     {    $this->connect();
          $this->pdo->prepare("Some SQL that saves some stuff");
          // now do some DB-related pdo work
     }

}
```

My question is - is this reasonable? Is this the way a lot of you code?

As I see it, there are 3 options:

1. The way I'm doing it - connecting to the database only in those
       functions that are database related. But these means *each* time I run a DB-related function.
2. Open a connection in the constructor, in this case I only open it once, but also end up opening it even when I don't need it, so I feel like sometimes I'll be creating
       connections for nothing.
3. On the other hand, I could use a singleton database class like this:

   [PDO Connections - max connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231769/pdo-connections-max-connections)

I do have up to three related objects on a page, and sometimes I do and sometimes I don't need to connect to the DB more than once on a page. which design is safer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use DI, in your class to instantiate a connection, when your object is defined ex:

```
class foo{
    public $conn;

    function __construct($conn){
    $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    function doSomething(){
    }
}
```

Now, if you find yourself, not wanting to instanciate a connection, whenever you 
are on a page/work that does not need database connection, and significantly slows your page, while trying to connect, use the PDO attribute

`ATT_PERSISTENT` property like:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 
                array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true )
        );

$object = new foo($conn);
```

Simply, once, you open a page, and connection is establish the `ATTR_PERSISTENT` method will store that connection, pretty much like sessions work, and will keep feeding your page, and helping you from creating a new connection to your db, every time you refresh a page, or go on to another page. Try, it.. and you'll see how faster your pages will load.

Comment: what is "DI"? I don't fully understand what you mean. When will the second snippet of code be used? Let's say I'm on a page where I instantiate the object `Product`. And I'm going to use the object for a long time on the page but at the end I need to save it, like this `$product->save();` So if I start the page with `$p = new Product; $p->setVals(some values);`, what should I do at the end of the page and when should I add your second code with `ATT_PERSISTENT`?

Comment: as far as the `ATTR_PERSISTENT` is concerned, you can add it anywhere,   don't worry about it. As I said, it is a bit like sessions, just open it once, and it will keep maintaining the connection attribute on your page, and the connection will terminate once, you close the page. Now, DI is a short for Dependency Injection. you can google it, or see [this](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2013/01/dependency-injection-programming-with.html) to get some idea. It is very important way of handling connections that exists today

Answer (score 2):

You can just use lazy way.

```
 protected $pdo;

 function connect()
 {
 if ($this->pdo === null)
    {
    $this->pdo = new PDO( "mysql:host=".zConfig::read('hostname').";dbname=".zConfig::read('database'), zConfig::read('username'), zConfig::read('password'));
    $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
 }
```

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484790/auto-connecting-to-pdo-only-if-needed).